# Powering a water pump with nodemcu

Tags: power, fluid-pump, nodemcu

I want to use a nodemcu to water my plants. I connected a pump with a 2N2222 transistor (I know i should add a diode and a pull down on the gate). The pump is DSL370 and when it is off i measure 4.4V on the Vin pin while using a 2A charger connected to the USB port. When the pump is active, the vin voltage drops to 4.1V and the LCD becomes hard to read. I measured the current the pump uses and it is 300mA. What is the reason for the voltage drop? I thought the charger should be able to handle it.
Also, as i saw at
http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-projects-tips-and-more/powering-the-esp-12e-nodemcu-development-board/
The power from the USB is connected to the Vin via a diode so the Vin and the esp8266 power should not affect each other.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: what is "2A charger connected to the USB port"? Do you have type-C USB?

Comment: Did you actually connect the GND on the NodeMCU?

Comment: wire it to vin instead of the usb socket to avoid blowing out the nodemcu's diode and taking the voltage hit.

Comment: Of course GND is connected to the NodeMcu, missed it in the sketch.

Comment: @dandavis what "it" are you talking about?

Comment: @Maple: the usb adapter. aside, most USB chargers supply at least 1A, better ones (ex: 1 w/amazon fire tablet) pump out 2A@5V w/o negotiation. I have ~40 different chargers (don't ask) and none of them are limited to .1a or even .5a, save a few that are labeled ~400ma (spec be damned)

Comment: @dandavis It absolutely does not matter where OP connects 5V source to, as long as all other devices connected to this source directly.

Comment: @Maple: that's true, i thought the pin would be easier than the microUSB, but i suppose it could be split upstream. touche.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you can connect USB power to VU input or USB jack and draw power from Vin trough schottky inside, as in your picture. However there are several problems with this:

1. schottky will drop USB voltage by at least 0.6V.
2. If your USB power comes from PC then you cannot draw more than 100mA without negotiation with the host. And PC is allowed to drop to 4.4V in these conditions.
3. If your USB power comes from external charger through the jack then you cannot communicate with PC at the same time.

Another option is to connect LCD+Motor to VU pin, bypassing the schottky. In this case you can power the board via USB jack from external power supply and everything will work fine. But the problems #2 and #3 will still remain.

So, the solution is to power LCD and Motor directly from charger, if their voltages compatible, or through 5V voltage regulator if not. The same supply wire will also power nodeMCU through Vin pin. Main points here are:

1. Motor power never comes through either schottky or internal nodeMCU regulator;
2. Motor power never comes from PC USB port.

However you can separate LCD from motor and power it from either 3.3V or VU pins, depending on what voltage it needs. Then you will have working LCD whether you power nodeMCU from PC or from external charger.

Comment: Ok got it, will use a regulator and connect it to Vin.
By the way, aren't phones charged with more than 100mA?

Comment: The phones *negotiate* the available power with the computer after establishing data connection. That is why you sometimes cannot fast charge the phone if it is not recognized by the operation system.

Comment: "will use a regulator and connect it to Vin" still does not make sense. What regulator? 3.3V as in that article is only necessary if you want to power other 3.3V devices. And you connect it to 3.3V pins, not Vin. If your motor and LCD require 5V you can use 5V wall adapter to power up nodemcu (via Vin pin) and all other devices directly.

Comment: I am not connecting the USB charger to a computer but to wall socket.
I have a regulator that can output 1A@6V and i can use a voltage divider.
But theoretically, what is the difference between taking a 2A@5V USB charger, splitting its wires and connecting the power to Vin VS connecting it to the USB socket of the NodeMcu (Aside from the diode voltage drop)?

Comment: OK, now I got it. If you have answered my very first comment we could have avoided a lot of misunderstanding. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: I've updated an answer.

Comment: This is not a particularly clear or accurate answer.  You have the voltage drop of a shottky diode wrong, and you start with a long divergence through situations which do not apply.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Umm.. 1N5819 has 0.6~0.9V forward drop. What exactly wrong? As for long divergence - that is the result of misunderstanding. I'll clean up the answer, but let me point out that all I said still applicable if the connections made as in the drawing or if the board is powered from PC.

Comment: Here it is. Better?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have no intention of using PC with the pump, so no problem there. I still don't see why in my current connection the voltage drops from 4.4V to 4.1V when the pump is active. Is the current limited by the diode?

Comment: See #1 at the beginning of my answer. 5V - 0.6~0.9V = 4.4~4.1V. It is simple forward voltage drop on a diode, precisely as in 1N5819 datasheet. Diode does not limit current, it drops voltage, the higher current the more voltage drop. If you connect it to PC you would see even less, down to something like 3.8V. I understand now that you are not going to have PC connected as a power source, but you do need it to program nodeMCU and maybe change something in the future. That is why my final advice was to leave USB jack open and power through Vin pin.